# REST API vs Direct Access Code

Tags: javascript, php, html, static

With the rise popularity of REST API and Static Website Generators these days, I'm a bit confused regarding the performance of using REST API vs accessing the code directly.

If I have a piece of code that I want to reuse, should I turn it into a REST API or just leave as it is for faster performance?

The code in question is written in PHP and I plan to use Jekyll or another Static Website Generator and JavaScript to communicate with the code.

For example, to access the code directly, I would use GET http://example.com/file.php?function and return the pain result. To access through REST API, GET http://example.com/function and return the JSON result.

Based on the speed difference, which loads faster in a web browser, REST API or direct? Or are they the same speed?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "raw code"?

Comment: Going to need to see your existing code and a far more detailed desciption of your problem

Comment: @SLaks What I meant is a piece of PHP code. A procedure piece of code, neither a function nor a class. Thanks.

Comment: It depends what your code does. If it's something that you imagine to be consumed by many clients then yeah make a rest api. It sounds like you're entering the realm of SAAS. I make a lot of dynamic PDF files... so I made a REST API that can be used across many clients.

Comment: @IanBrindley I know what an API is. What I want to know is that does the REST API effect the performance of the code? Thanks.

Comment: no I don't think so but REST API have a less data transport then normal load html page. So performance on server side should not have a effect but for clients can have bigger effect because you can change small peaces dynamicaly

Comment: @RobbyChen If you think about the architecture of a REST API, it is the network latency that may slow you down.

Comment: @IanBrindley Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on how you're gonna reuse your code.

REST API is your choice if you need to reuse the function by another web application.. otherwise, direct code access would be faster.

REST API would isolate your function and make it reusable, but it would add a unecessary completexity too.

Other thing you might as well taking into account is the amount of data your gonna traffic... REST is recommended to traffic small chunks of data.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I think I will use REST API for a bigger block of code to minimize the data traffic and access the code directly for the smaller one.